# Add a new file location to the SalesForce File Selector Drop-down

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have written an apex class that will create a PDF quote and attach it to an opportunity.  I'm trying to figure out how I can access those attachments when I go to send an email from within SalesForce and then click on Attach File.

[image]

I want to figure out how to see another location in the drop-down show in the image above that has the PDFs attached to the opportunity.

Comment: can u tell me how u attach a file to opportunity. i have to do the same.thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took a slightly different approach.  When I create the PDF as a note I also put a copy in a sub-folder in the Documents directory.

Now I can access that document from the Email Tab. I'm looking to add a trigger to clear out old quotes to keep the folder from getting too large.